# Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 in docker-compose while connecting redis

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I am getting connection  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 while working with docker-compose to use **Redis** with **node js**.
I used the same host name and service name in Redis but still got an error.

My node js code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
    port: 6379,
    host: 'redis'
});
client.connect();
client.on('connect', (err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log('Redis Connected..!');
});

const app = express();
app.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
    let key = req.query['name'];
    if(key){
        let value = await client.get(key);
        if(value){
            value++;
            client.set(key,value);
            res.send(`Hello ${key}, ${value}!`);
            console.log(`${key}, ${value}`);
        }
        else{
            value = 1;
            client.set(key,value); 
            res.send(`Hello ${key}, ${value}!`);
            console.log(`${key}, ${value}`);
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Name not passed!");
        res.send("Hello World!");
    }
});
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`App is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis: 
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: client
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 6379
  app:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

and what I am getting on console is

```
C:\Users\ashok\Desktop\Practice>docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/3
 - Network practice_default  Created                                                                                                        0.1s
 - Container client          Created                                                                                                        1.1s
 - Container app             Created                                                                                                        0.3s
Attaching to app, client
client  | 1:C 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.885 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
client  | 1:C 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.886 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
client  | 1:C 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.886 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
client  | 1:M 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.889 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
client  | 1:M 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.890 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
client  | 1:M 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.891 # Server initialized
client  | 1:M 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.891 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
client  | 1:M 02 Apr 2022 11:08:28.893 * Ready to accept connections
app     |
app     | > practice@1.0.0 start
app     | > node app.js
app     |
app     | Server is live at port: 3000
app     | node:internal/process/promises:279
app exited with code 1
app     |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
app     |             ^
app     |
app     | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
app     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
app     | Emitted 'error' event on Commander instance at:
app     |     at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:339:14)
app     |     at RedisSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
app     |     at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_connect (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:117:14)
app     |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
app     |     at async Commander.connect (/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:162:9) {
app     |   errno: -111,
app     |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
app     |   syscall: 'connect',
app     |   address: '127.0.0.1',
app     |   port: 6379
app     | }
```

what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: It looks like [`redis.createClient()`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md) doesn't directly accept `host:` as a parameter; either it wants a `url:`, or it wants the `host:` and `port:` inside a `socket:` object.  (Configuring it to point at `redis` is correct in a Compose context, but that shouldn't resolve to 127.0.0.1.)  Does changing the `createClient()` call help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had tried specifying host and port in the client creation too, and that didn't work.
I found that using

```
const client = redis.createClient({
url: 'redis://redis:6379'
});
```

fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

You are using docker, so the default host will not work and the container name will be your host which is ***client*** in your case. So if you want to connect with Redis then you have to do something like this -

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
       port: 6379,
       host: 'client'
    }
});

// OR

const client = redis.createClient({
    url: 'redis://client:6379'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, but solution is

```
let redisClient = redis.createClient({
  url: 'redis://redis:6379',
  legacyMode: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this work perfectly.

In **docker-compose.yaml**

```
docker-compose up -d redis
docker-compose up -d app
```

Don't need write the port in connection url.

```
redis.createClient({
    url: 'redis://redis'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the `container_name` for Redis fixed the problem.

So, in ".env" I have:

`REDIS_HOST=service-redis`