# Connection refused Redis Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, redis, containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect to a master-replica redis architecture, deployed in Kubernetes.

Following the official tutorial from K8 (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/), i applied deployments and services.

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/redis-master-56657b6598-c9292   1/1     Running   0          32m
pod/redis-slave-6f88cf4d8-cmgrr     1/1     Running   0          28m

NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    104m
service/redis-master   ClusterIP   10.106.125.158   <none>        6379/TCP   32m
service/redis-slave    ClusterIP   10.97.68.199     <none>        6379/TCP   26m

NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/redis-master   1/1     1            1           32m
deployment.apps/redis-slave    1/1     1            1           28m

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/redis-master-56657b6598   1         1         1       32m
replicaset.apps/redis-slave-6f88cf4d8     1         1         1       28m
```

This is what I see when I type `kubectl get all`: in my opinion, everything looks ok.

However, in my main Javascript application:

```
console.log('Redis Application starting ')

const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const app = express();

const redisMaster = redis.createClient({ host: 'redis-master', port: 6379 });
const redisSlave = redis.createClient({ host: 'redis-slave', port: 6379 });
```

when I run it, a `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379` message appears.

Is there something I am missing?

I am using WSL2, so Minikube is running on another layer of container, could it be an hint?

Here the redis-master-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-master
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: "docker.io/redis:latest"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

and here the redis-slave deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-slave
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: slave
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        role: slave
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: slave
        image: elsospi/redis-slave-img:v1.1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

Then I wrote both the replica and the master services:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-master
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-slave
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: slave
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: slave
    tier: backend
```

Comment: Do you need a `socket:` option in the `redis.createClient()` call, as in [Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 in docker-compose while connecting redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717395/getting-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-16379-in-docker-compose-while-conne)?